# npm audit security report - отчет об обеспечении безопасности

Tags: gulp, npm

Помогите устранить данные проблемы?

/* найдено 6 уязвимостей (2 низких, 4 умеренных) -- found 6 vulnerabilities (2 low, 4 moderate)*/

```
  Moderate        Prototype pollution

  Package         hoek

  Patched in      > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3

  Dependency of   gulp-sass [dev]

  Path            gulp-sass > node-sass > node-gyp > request > hawk > boom > hoek

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/566
```

---

```
  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         debug

  Patched in      >= 2.6.9 < 3.0.0 || >= 3.1.0

  Dependency of   browser-sync [dev]

  Path            browser-sync > localtunnel > debug

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534
```

Comment: А отчет послностью читали? А то что в секции Remediation делали?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Что за секция Remediation? Можно по подробней.

Comment: В самом конце написано:  See the full report for details.(Подробнее см. Полный отчет.) Но, я не знаю где находится полный отчет.